# Config Processing Error on circle-ci [Build error]

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, config, amazon-cloudfront, circleci

I am facing a problem with Config Processing Error on circle-ci  "

**Config Processing Error**

```
 !/bin/sh -eo pipefail
 Unable to parse YAML
 while parsing a block collection
  in 'string', line 22, column 13:
                 - node_modules
                 ^
 expected <block end>, but found '?'
  in 'string', line 23, column 13:
                 key: app-{{ checksum \"package.js ... 

 -------
Warning: This configuration was auto-generated to show you the message above.
Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect.
false

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

this is [my repo](https://github.com/taiga-programming/cinema-app/blob/develop/.circleci/config.yml)

Answer (score 0):

The causing the error was one row is off.

**After fixed**

```
  -save_cache:
      paths:
        - node_modules
      key: app-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
```

**Before fixed**

```
　-save_cache:
  　paths:
    - node_modules
     key: app-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
```